# Restricting upload until the admin approved the uploaded file in Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

i am new in django.I am doing a project where user can upload image.But i want to make sure that the user can not upload image or file until the admin approved it.now how can i do this,have prepared models for this,but for inexperience in django i can not complete it or you can say i have no clue,now help me if you can, i am giving a very simple code here.

This is my forms.py for the upload image...

```
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    photo = forms.ImageField(
                      label='Select a file'
                     )
```

and this is my models.py...

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

 class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.nullBooleanField()
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True,auto_now = False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 80 , blank = False , null = True)
    approved_by = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

here i make a field for approved as a Boolean field.

and this is view for file/image upload...

```
def UserImageUpload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
        if approved:
        newdoc = Photo(photo = request.FILES['photo'],user = request.user)
        newdoc.save()
        else:

    else:
    form = DocumentForm()

    uploaded_image = Photo.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('myprofile/user_image_upload.html',{'uploaded_image':uploaded_image,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and this is the template for file or image upload...

```
 {% extends 'base.html'%}
 {% block title%}User Image Upload {% endblock %}
 {%block content%}

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.photo.label_tag }} {{ form.photo.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.photo.errors }}
            {{ form.photo }}
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>

 {%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this: 
1.User upload image and you set approved to false. 
2.On admin page you can change approved to true.
3.Before you display image on site you check if it is approved.